# Will emergency heat hurt my heat pump during defrosting?

Tags: heat-pump

I am using my emergency heat during the defrosting stage of my heat pump. Is this all right? If not, what can I do while it's defrosting?

Comment: Curious... how long does the defrost stage last?

Answer (score 1):

Emergency heat comes from heat coils in the air mover on your system. It should be fine but your electric bill will be higher because of the high amperage they draw compared to the heat pump.